# passing string with spaces to node cli-parser

Tags: yargs, node-commander, minimist

```
var minimist = require("minimist")

const a = minimist(`executable --param "a b"`.split(' '))
console.log(a)
```

https://runkit.com/embed/57837xcuv5v0

actual output:

`Object {_: ["executable", "b\""], param: "\"a"}`

expected output:

`Object {_: ["executable"], param: "a b"}`

---

I'm also seeing same result when using `yargs` and `commander`.

It's strange because `jest` is using `yargs` and jest accept the following command: `jest -t "test name with spaces"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example code, the problem is your preparation of the string array which has broken up the string-with-spaces before the parser gets to see it:

```
$ node -e 'console.log(`executable --param "a b"`.split(" "))'
[ 'executable', '--param', '"a', 'b"' ]
```

A simple fix when manually setting up the arguments is to construct the array of parameters yourself, instead of using a string and `split`, like:

```
$ node -e 'console.log(["executable", "--param", "a b"])'   
[ 'executable', '--param', 'a b' ]
```

or

```
const a = minimist(['executable', '--param', 'a b'])
```

---

If what you need to do is break up a single string into arguments like the shell does, that is not done by Commander, or minimist.

You could look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/shell-quote which has a parse command.

---

Yargs *does* have a mode where it does the splitting, if you pass in a single string rather than an array of strings.

```js
const yargs = require('yargs/yargs');
const argv = yargs('executable --param "a b"').parse();
console.log(argv);
```

```
% node index.js 
{ _: [ 'executable' ], param: 'a b', '$0': 'index.js' }
```

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: I will add some examples

Comment: but idk what is the command before runtime. this answer doesnt help. sory

Comment: Where is this command string coming from? All of commander and yargs and minimist take an array of arguments, like from process.argv, after the shell has already processed the raw command line and split it into separate arguments.

Comment: it comes from the argv. you all answer is based on the fact that i know the keys and values. it makes no sense that i will even need help..........

Comment: When writing tests, you construct the argument array yourself and have to be careful about how you construct it. When you are passing process.argv, then splitting up the arguments is a different problem because what matters is how the shell does the splitting. I tried to explain what is wrong with your example but if that is not the issue, what are you actually doing and what behaviour are you actually seeing?

Comment: think that argv=`executable --param "a b"`. see the actual/expected output

Comment: Added shell-quote

Comment: thats far away from what was i looking for but it's the best there is. so thanks!! :)

Comment: @StavAlfi FYI Yargs can parse a single string, and I have added an example.